# How to stretch a div to the viewport bottom without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, viewport

How to stretch a div (not the size of the viewport) to the viewport bottom without using absolute positioning?

If I use absolute positioning to stretch my "main" div to the bottom on the viewport, then any newly added elements above main, say a nav bar, won't get re-positioned by the browser automatically since the "main" div with no longer be in the normal flow.

And I really don't want to be recalculating top & bottom positions of affected elements every time I add/remove a dynamic div (or other containing) in the normal flow if I have to go the absolute route.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/nFC9R/2/)**



**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        HEADER<br>
        <input id="btnNavBar" type="button" value="add/remove nav bar"/>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        MAIN CONTENT NEEDS TO STRETCH TO BOTTOM OF VIEWPORT, BUT NOT BE ABSOLUTE SO THAT IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY ADJUST FOR ANY NEWLY ADDED DYNAMIC ELEMENTS ABOVE IT SINCE IT'LL STILL BE IN THE NORMAL FLOW.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
#header {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
#main {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
}
/* UNCOMMENT THIS SECTION TO MAKE THE STRETCHING WORK WITH ABSOLUTE POSITIONING, 
    BUT NOT FOR ANY NEWLY ADDED ELEMENTS */
/*#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#main {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}*/
```

**JS:**

```
$('#btnNavBar').click(function(){
    var $navBar = $('#navBar');
    if ($navBar.length == 0)
    {
        $('<div>').prop('id','navBar').css({'height':'20px', 
            'background-color':'yellow', 'text-align':'center'})
            .text('Dynamically Added Nav Bar').insertAfter('#header');
    }
    else
        $navBar.remove();
});
```

Comment: It looks like it's already at full height in your fiddle (without AP). Is that different than what you want or not working in production?

Comment: @cantera25 - There's a scroll bar on the right as "main" is going past the bottom of the viewport to 100% the height of it's parent container which is too long by the length of the header (+ any other content after header and before "main").

Comment: Okay I understand - and there will be more content inserted between header and main after page load?

Comment: @cantera25 - yes. will be adding and removing content there so this will increase the overall height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your **CSS**

```
#wrapper:before
{
    content: '';
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
#main:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

and remove the `height:100%` from `#main`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/nFC9R/8/)

*Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, FF, Chrome.

1. didn't change your markup
2. didn't use absolute positioning
3. didn't use Script (Pure CSS solution)
4. fluid layout
5. cross-browser

Comment: Excellent answer, but it's not working for me in IE or Opera. Can you double check IE again?

Comment: which IE are you using?

Comment: IE 10 (latest), IE 9 (latest).

Comment: I'm also solving for IE7, IE8, and Opera as well, but I'm happy to use CSS hacks fix them. If that's even possible.

Comment: Here's a snapshot from my IE10: http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/2984/uvnf.jpg as you can see, its working fine.

Comment: screenshot looks the same as mine, but nothing happens when I click the button in IE 10 (or 9).

Comment: I just checked again. this time also on IE8. its working fine with all browsers. do you want me to take all those with snapshots? (before and after the click)

Comment: Okay got it. It was the JQuery 2.0.2 version not working on IE or Opera. When I switched it back to 1.9.1 again, it worked in those browsers. Not sure why the 2.0.2 version works for you in IE and not me. I'm on Win7, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: oh.. that because when I've tried the clicking in all browsers, it was from a local file, that uses JQuery 1.9.1 lol. nice catch there. +1